# Tag Synonyms for Beta

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since not many of us can suggest Tag Synonyms yet, here is a list for when we do have the ability to do so:

- [it](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it) -> [information-technology](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/information-technology)
- [ri](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ri) -> [rhode-island](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhode-island) or [rhose-island-usa](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhose-island-usa)

  - If the above goes to the use part then [new-york](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york)->[new-york-usa](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-york-usa)

Feel free to edit with more suggestions

Answer (score 3):

For future reference: you can just edit these when there's only 1 question. Setting up lots of synonyms when there's no clear evidence of a problem yet isn't usually productive.

Also, see: [Overcoming the location specificity of questions](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53/overcoming-the-location-specificity-of-questions)

Finally, when you're discussing a specific tag or set of related tags, try to start a meta discussion that's clearly specific to those tags. Put them in the title so folks who're interested will find it. **Do not** try to create a gigantic list of tags that need to be changed; this does nothing to attract the attention of folks who're interested in those tags and becomes unwieldy in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [it](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/it) looks kind of out of place.

As far tagging every state or location around the world, though, I don't know if it's such a good idea in the first place; heck, that's around 250 tags, easily.